# What is the cause of the warning : Pattern match is redundant?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to solve an exercises that Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice versa but I'm getting this warning:

```
Pattern match is redundant
In an equation for ‘tempToC’: tempToC temp = ...compile(-Woverlapping-patterns)
```

I am new to Haskell and need help understanding the cause of the warning.

```
module Temperature (tempToC, tempToF) where

{- Implement the function `tempToC` to convert
`  Fahrenheit to Celsius                    -}

tempToC :: Integer -> Float
tempToC temp = error "Implement this function."
tempToC temp = fromIntegral (temp - 32 ) / 1.8 --line of the warning

{- Implement the function `tempToF` to convert
   Celsius to Fahrenheit                    -}

tempToF :: Float -> Integer
tempToF temp = error "Implement this function."
tempToF temp = ceiling  (temp * 1.8 + 32) --line of the warning
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove the lines `tempToC temp = error "Implement this function."` and `tempToF temp = error "Implement this function."`. Since `temp` just names a new variable, it will match anything, so those lines will prevent the lines below them from ever running.

Comment: OMG ! I was very dumb not to see that.
Thanks a lot :)